# Controlling bootstrap dropdown menu with it's grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

I am using bootstrap framework for a project and having a tiny problem with dropdown menu. Here is the link;

http://erkano.com/neu

You will see when you hover over "YÖNETİM" button that the dropdown appears. I, however, want this dropdown has the same width value, that is col-md-5, with the whole menu bar. The reason I could not deal with it is that the dropdown should stay in the first button, that is col-md-2 in the col-md-5.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay now that I understand the question.

You can make the dropdown menu full width by... give that drop down menu the class container.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-dropdown container" id="menu1">
```

I quickly did this from inspecting and it made it almost full width.. this in practice kinda of works. You get the idea of making the drop down a set width and using javascript to make it responsive...

But I also did this and it kinda of work as well. Your layout is weird and breaks responsively anyways but here I changed the class:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
width: 95%; <-- I added this
}
```

and

```
dropdown-menu {
position: fixed; <-- changed to fixed instead of absolute
top: 13%; <-- changed to 13% instead of 100%
left: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0px;
margin: 2px 0px 0px;
list-style: outside none none;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

you can fiddle with the css to get the exact size you want but that in a nutshell will work.

Comment: I will design inside of the dropdown differently. It will look like the dropdown on this site actually,

http://www.cornell.edu/

By the way, col-md-12 does not work.. Because <ul> is in the "col-md-2" div.

Comment: oh did I misunderstand what was asked? I thought you want the drop down menu to be the size of 1 li element. did you want it to spread across the entire length of the main menu?

Comment: Yes entire main menu. this is the challange :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It will be better if I can wrap the dropdown menu with col-md-5 class because if i can do that, it will have the same responsive behaviour with the main-menu, which is smth i want to achieve. The layout is not fully-responsive for now, i know. Like i said i have to wrap the dropdown with col-md-5.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. I will post it when i am finished

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown main-menu-dropdown-container">
  <li class="col-md-2">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="main-menu-dropdown-1">YÖNETİM</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-dropdown col-md-12" aria-labelledby="main-menu-dropdown-1">
   <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have edited the html part like this and the css part like this;

```
.main-menu-dropdown-container:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.main-menu-dropdown {
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    top: 60px !important;
    border:0 !important;
    border-top:1px solid #F3F3F3 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.59) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.59) !important;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.59) !important;
}
```

This works perfectly for me. I did not even change anything on the original grid system and the dropdown system on bootstrap.